# Plot percentages on y-axis

Tags: r, plot

I'm plotting a graph using this

```
plot(dates,returns)
```

I would like to have the `returns` expressed as percentages instead of numbers. `0.1` would become `10%`. Also, the numbers on the y-axis appear tilted 90 degrees on the left. Is it possible to make them appear horizontally?

Comment: You're going to want to read some documentation. Specifically, `?axis` and `?par`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is one way using `las=TRUE` to turn the labels on the y-axis and `axis()` for the new y-axis with adjusted labels.

```
dates <-  1:10
returns <- runif(10)

plot(dates, returns, yaxt="n")
axis(2, at=pretty(returns), lab=pretty(returns) * 100, las=TRUE)
```

Comment: Just multiplying by 100 does not put the % symbol next to the number

Comment: `.., lab=paste0(pretty(returns) * 100, " %"), ..`

Comment: Why `las = TRUE`? When looking up ?par `las` can take a numerical value from 0 - 3. But it doesn't say anything about taking a logicals... Thx!

Answer (score 10):

If you use ggplot you can use the [scales](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scales/scales.pdf) package.

```
library(scales)
plot + scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
```

Comment: He was asking for basic R plot rather than ggplot2

Comment: As of Nov 2017 this needs to be modified a bit: `plot + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)`

Answer (score 4):

```
library(scales)
dates <-  1:100
returns <- runif(100)
yticks_val <- pretty_breaks(n=5)(returns)
plot(dates, returns, yaxt="n")
axis(2, at=yticks_val, lab=percent(yticks_val))
```

Highlights:

1. No need to explicitly add "%"
2. Manually fix the number of y-ticks to be consistent with further plots. Here I chose 5.

[image: See]

Combining two answers together @rengis @vladiim

Comment: Where are you getting the functions pretty_breaks() and percent() from?

Comment: To answer my own question pretty_breaks() is from the 'scales' package and percent() is from 'memisc'. Would be a good idea to import those so your code is actually runnable.