# Y axis to percent using barplot

Tags: r, bar-chart, axis

Gretings

I need to change my barplot that the y axis shows in percent. This is my code:

```
grafico=barplot(as.matrix(w),las=2,beside=T, horiz=F,,ces.names=1.5,col=c("lightblue","lightgrey","darkgrey"),cex.axis=1, cex.names=0.78, main = "Figura 2. Vivienda")
legend(20,20, row.names(w), col=c("lightblue","lightgrey","darkgrey"),cex = 0.75,lwd=5)
```

This is what I have right now:

[image: barplot]

Thanks!

Comment: `axis(2, at=pretty(y), lab=pretty(y) * 100, las=TRUE)`

Comment: Take a look at [This previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11674637/4752675)